# Kubernetes garbage collection clean docker components

Tags: docker, kubernetes

Currently running a k8s cluster however occasionally I get memory issues. The following error will pop up,

`Failed create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to create a sandbox for pod "<web app>": Error response from daemon: devmapper: Thin Pool has 6500 free data blocks which is less than minimum required 7781 free data blocks. Create more free space in thin pool or use dm.min_free_space option to change behavior`

I can resolve this by manually running `docker ps -a -f status=exited -q | xargs -r docker rm -v`

However I want Kubernetes to do this work itself. Currently in my kublet config I have:

```
evictionHard:
  imagefs.available: 15%
  memory.available: "100Mi"
  nodefs.available: 10%
  nodefs.inodesFree: 5%
imageGCHighThresholdPercent: 85
imageGCLowThresholdPercent: 80
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You need to check container collection [settings](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/kubelet-garbage-collection/#container-collection)

Comment: Im not seeing those options in here https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/staging/src/k8s.io/kubelet/config/v1beta1/types.go

Comment: Looks they are [deprecated](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/out-of-resource/#deprecation-of-existing-feature-flags-to-reclaim-disk) and you have new flags for imageGC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the error you've posted seems to me you are using "[devicemapper](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/device-mapper-driver/)" as storage driver.

> The `devicemapper` storage driver is deprecated in Docker Engine 18.09, and will be removed in a future release. It is recommended that users of the `devicemapper` storage driver migrate to `overlay2`.

I should suggest you use "**overlay2**" as storage drive, unless you are running a non-support OS. See [here](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/storagedriver/selectadriver/#docker-ce) the support OS versions.

You can check your actual storage drive using `docker info` command, you will get an output like this:

```
Client:
 Debug Mode: false

Server:
 Containers: 21
  Running: 18
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 3
 Images: 11
 Server Version: 19.03.5
 Storage Driver: devicemapper <<== See here
  Pool Name: docker-8:1-7999625-pool
  Pool Blocksize: 65.54kB
...
```

>
Supposing you want to change the storage drive from `devicemapper` to `overlay2`, you need to following this steps:

***Changing the storage driver makes existing containers and images inaccessible on the local system. Use  `docker save`  to save any images you have built or push them to Docker Hub or a private registry before changing the storage driver, so that you do not need to re-create them later.***

Before following this procedure, you must first meet all the [prerequisites](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/overlayfs-driver/#prerequisites).

1. Stop Docker.

   ```
   $ sudo systemctl stop docker
   ```
2. Copy the contents of  `/var/lib/docker`  to a temporary location.

   ```
   $ cp -au /var/lib/docker /var/lib/docker.bk
   ```
3. If you want to use a separate backing filesystem from the one used by  `/var/lib/`, format the filesystem and mount it into  `/var/lib/docker`. Make sure add this mount to  `/etc/fstab`  to make it permanent.
4. Edit  `/etc/docker/daemon.json`. If it does not yet exist, create it. Assuming that the file was empty, add the following contents.

   ```
   {
     "storage-driver": "overlay2"
   }
   ```

   Docker does not start if the  `daemon.json`  file contains badly-formed JSON.
5. Start Docker.

   ```
   $ sudo systemctl start docker
   ```
6. Verify that the daemon is using the  `overlay2`  storage driver. Use the  `docker info`  command and look for  `Storage Driver`  and  `Backing filesystem`.

```
Client:
 Debug Mode: false

Server:
 Containers: 35
  Running: 15
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 20
 Images: 11
 Server Version: 19.03.5
 Storage Driver: overlay2 <=== HERE
  Backing Filesystem: extfs <== HERE
  Supports d_type: true
```

Extracted from [Docker Documentation.](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/overlayfs-driver/)